# How long did it take to set up a portable runway?

Tags: runways

How long did it take to set up those metal runways? Were the metal sheets spiked into the ground? How big were they? Also, how are commercial runways built?

Comment: What are you talking about? What "portable runway" are you asking about? Where was it built? When?

Comment: Welcome to aviation. SE! [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/826/62) is sightly related. If you're new here please take the [tour] to see how the site works. We prefer one question at a time, for example.

Comment: Which runways?  That might help us answer the rest of your questions.

Comment: It really depends on "where".

Comment: You should remove the "also..." part of your question and ask that as a separate thread.

Comment: The last of your question is an whole question, you may find that most runways are made of [asphalt](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33430/why-are-most-runways-made-of-asphalt-and-not-concrete) and thus you can narrow this question to difference between runway and streets for building asphalt surfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your friend. Try it. "perforated metal airstrip"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marston_Mat

"A runway two hundred feet wide and 5000 feet (1500 m) long could be created within two days by a small team of engineers."